# How to check if query return no result in PDO

Tags: php, arrays, oracle, pdo

I'm pretty sure this question have been asked a lot by community, but i haven't found any good answer.

i have this code :

```
$keyword = '%'.strtoupper($_POST['keyword']).'%';
$limitMaterial = 'AS-%';
$findMaterial = $oracle->prepare('SELECT inventory_item_id, segment1, description, inventory_item_status_code FROM mtl_system_items_b WHERE segment1 LIKE ? AND (segment1 LIKE ? OR description LIKE ?)');
$findMaterial->bindParam(1, $limitMaterial, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$findMaterial->bindParam(2, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$findMaterial->bindParam(3, $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$findMaterial->execute();
$checkRow = $findMaterial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$boldKeyword = '<font color="red"><b>' . $keyword . '</b></font>';

if($checkRow !== false){
    var_dump($checkRow); // this is for testing only
    foreach($findMaterial as $dataMaterial){
        var_dump($dataMaterial); // this is for testing only
        $dataMaterial = array_change_key_case($dataMaterial,CASE_LOWER);
        $code = str_ireplace($keyword,$boldKeyword,$dataMaterial['segment1']);
        $desc = str_ireplace($keyword,$boldKeyword,$dataMaterial['description']);
        if(isset($_POST['idf'])){
            $idf = $_POST['idf'];
            echo '<div class="show" align="left" onclick="select('.$idf.',this); return false;"><span>'.$code.'</span><span style="visibility: hidden; font-size:1px;" class="find_material_'.$idf.'">'.$dataMaterial['segment1'].'</span></br>'.$desc.'</div>'; 
        } else {
            echo '<div class="show" align="left"><span>'.$code.'</span><span style="visibility: hidden; font-size:1px;" class="basic_code">'.$dataMaterial['segment1'].'</span></br>'.$desc.'</div>'; 
        }
    }
} else {
    echo '<div class="show" align="left">Part Code Not Found</div>'; 
}

$findMaterial = null;
```

What i want to ask is, *how to check if my query returned a result or not?*. My current code is working, but i have an issue that this line :

```
$checkRow = $findMaterial->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Take 1 row from results, so i'm missing 1 row in foreach loop. I've tried fetchColumn() (where it have same issue), and rowCount() (where it return 0 for SELECT statement).

If possible i want to avoid using "SELECT COUNT(1) FROM [table]" to check if data exist, or doing what happen in foreach loop outside it just for that 1 row.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check your query return result or not  by using `COUNT()` with out using `SELECT COUNT(1) FROM..` this as

```
$checkRow = $findMaterial->fetchAll();
if (count($checkRow) > 0) {
    foreach ($checkRow as $dataMaterial) {
        // your code
    }
} else {
    echo "NO RESULT FOUND";
}
```

Comment: but the problem is with that $checkRow line take 1 row from the result, making foreach can't access that taken row.

Comment: change `foreach($findMaterial as $dataMaterial){` to `foreach ($checkRow as $dataMaterial) {`

Comment: ah i'm sorry, didn't see that, i'll try it right away. thank you.

Comment: ah sorry, somehow $checkRow returned as String inside that foreach, and it throw an error at "array_change_key_case" being supplied by String

Comment: use `fetchAll();` instead `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)`